# Network activating; if ( !current_user_can( ‘manage_options’ ) ) locks me out…

Tags: plugins, multisite, wp-admin

iHi,

I use this snippet in a plugin;

```
if ( ! ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) )
  do something
 }
```

but problem is, when network activating this on a multi-site installation, I get locked out of admin pages. WP says “You don’t have authority to this page” or something (translating from Swedish).

I have, by trial and error, limited down the problem to the function "current_user_can" but is_super_admin gives the same result. I get locked out.
Please note that this only happens when network activating on a multisite installation. If I activate the plugin per site everything works as expected.
See [github](https://github.com/joje47/NGO-portal/blob/master/ngo-menu-deactivate/ngo-menu-deactivate.php#L75) for an example of how I try to implement it.

How come? I’ve tried it out many times and tried to tweak the code, but I can't get it to work.

Any better way of checking it user does NOT have authority to manage options (does not have admin capabilities)?

Comment: Perhaps it's related to `if (!(current_user_can('manage_options'))) {` being run immediately rather than being used within a callback function fired on a hook? Can you try wrapping this functionality in a function and firing it on  `wp_loaded`? ([`wp_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) seems early enough.)

Comment: I can't mark your comment as a solution. I will mark my sum up of your answer as a solution tomorrow.

Comment: Works for me! Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your advice. In fact it is a hook that I fire of with this check. It looks like this (an example, the check is done in two places for different user levels and in two different plugins)

```
// Down locks me out of admin area if network activated...
```

if (!(current_user_can('manage_options'))) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ngo_remove_eo' );
}

and the function is;

```
function ngo_remove_eo() {
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=event' );
```

}

I changed it to this;

```
   add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'eongo_cleanup' );

function eongo_cleanup() {
    if (!(current_user_can('manage_options'))) {  
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ngo_remove_eo' );
    }

    if(!is_super_admin()){
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ngo_remove_eosubmenu', 99 );
    add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'remove_eopost_custom_fields' );
    }
}
```

and now it works :) Thanks a lot Dave.